# How can I make Chrome format numbers in console log with `_` as thousands separator?

Tags: google-chrome

I often like opening the dev tools console and reading logs.

However, the logs often have messages like `[12668,13530,77,8489,28085,22500,18342,6294,1786,10555,28069,5472]`, which have large numbers that are difficult to read since there are no thousands separators.

What setting on Chrome or Windows would allow me to make all JavaScript numbers automatically display with a thousands separator?

E.g. I'd like `12668` to appear as `12_668`.

I'm not asking a coding question. (If I were in control of the code, I'd know how to do it.)

---

UPDATE to clarify:

I want the numbers to *always* be formatted that way.

I don't want to need to do something manual each time.

I certainly don't want to copy and paste from the Google Chrome console to some other tool.

Comment: That could be possible using a browser extension for DevTools.

Comment: Copy, paste into a spreadsheet, and set column to show separators. That also will improve readability, since columns are cleanly separated, not with commas to further confuse the issue. Of course, clipboard could be saved to CSV and imported directly.